# How to give to the following integral a closed-form expression

Tags: calculus

We consider the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty  x^{–a} \exp(b/x –cx) W_{–p,0} (g/x) dx$$

where $W_{–p,0} (\cdot)$ is the Whittaker function, and $ a, b, c, p, g $ are the nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: What have you done on the subject ? Besides, could you recall a working defintion of Whittaker function ?

Comment: The defination of Whittaker functions can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function. In addition, a=p are nonnegtive real numbers